# Firebase Timestamp format to javascript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have converted a string into a date format in my firebase firestore database.
The date is stored as a timestamp and appears in the table as 11 December 2022 00:00:00. This seems to be correct as when I edit the date in firestore it gives the same result. In javascript I use 'new Date (data.date *1000).toDateString()' - the date displays as '11 December 3991'. The data.date displays as 'Timestamp(seconds=1645747200, nanoseconds=0)'.

Any help appreciated

I have tried everything online with no success.

Comment: Simply use the [toDate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.timestamp.md#timestamptodate) method